TypeError - ctx.request.body is not a function
I am trying making a simple RESTApi using Deno and Oak. Why am I getting this error
TypeError - ctx.request.body is not a function
request: { url: "http://localhost:8000/todos", method: "POST", hasBody: true }
response: { status: 500, type: "text", hasBody: true, writable: true }

This is the part of the code where I am getting this error.
import { Router } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v16.0.0/mod.ts';
const router = new Router();

interface Todo {
  id: string;
  text: string;
}

let todos: Array<Todo> = [];

router.get('/todos', (ctx, _) => {
  ctx.response.body = { todos: todos };
});

router.post('/todos', async (ctx) => {
  const reqBody = await ctx.request.body(); <--here
  console.log(reqBody);
});

router.put('/todos/:todoId', (ctx, _) => {});

router.delete('/todos/:todoId', (ctx, _) => {});

export default router;


Here is my app.ts file
import { Application } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';
import todoRoutes from './routes/todos.ts';

const app = new Application();

app.use(todoRoutes.routes());
app.use(todoRoutes.allowedMethods());

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });


I have searched all the answers on the internet. Everywhere they are using ctx.request.body()
But when I use it I am getting the error.

A cursory looks tells me this may be the old api and they use the Request object from Javascript now, which means it may be await ctx.request.json() instead

The body usually needs to be used with a method like ctx.request.body.json() or ctx.request.body.form().
https://deno.land/x/oak@v16.1.0#request-body
Edit: This was a newer update as far as I'm aware. The docs say with Oak 13.

import { Application, Router } from "@oak/oak";
const router = new Router();
const app = new Application();
router.post("/", async (ctx) => {
  const result = (await ctx.request.body.formData()).get("id");
  ctx.response.body =result;
});
app.listen({ port: 8080 });

this works for  multipart/form-data and application/x-www-form-urlencoded
router.post("/", async (ctx) => {
  const result = (await ctx.request.body.form()).get("id");

  
  ctx.response.body =result;
});

this works for application/x-www-form-urlencoded
